# Ejabberd Custom IQ handler: disconnecting user after receiving custom IQ stanza. Ejabberd 15.07

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm a beginner on Erlang-Ejabberd development and i want to create a module on top of Ejabberd 15.07. So i got some code as example in many posts and some tutorials to start developing my own module. Now i came out with this code to get started.

```
-module(mod_test)
-behaviour(gen_mod).

-ifndef(LAGER).
-define(LAGER, 1).
-endif.
-define(NS_SEEN, <<"jabber:iq:seen">>).

-include("ejabberd.hrl").
-include("logger.hrl").
-include("jlib.hrl").

-export([start/2, stop/1, process_sm_iq/3]).

start(Host, Opt) ->
    ?INFO_MSG(" mod_test starting   ", []),
    IQDisc = gen_mod:get_opt(iqdisc, Opt, fun gen_iq_handler:check_type/1, one_queue),

    gen_iq_handler:add_iq_handler(ejabberd_sm, Host, ?NS_SEEN, ?MODULE, process_sm_iq, IQDisc),
    ok.

stop(Host) ->
    ?INFO_MSG(" mod_test2 stopping  ", []),
    gen_iq_handler:remove_iq_handler(ejabberd_sm, Host, ?NS_SEEN),    
    ok.

process_sm_iq(_From, _To, #iq{type = get, xmlns = ?NS_SEEN} = IQ) ->
    ?INFO_MSG(" Processing IQ Get query:~n ~p   ", [IQ]),
    IQ#iq{type = result, sub_el = [{xmlelement, <<"value">>, [], [{xmlcdata, <<"Hello World of Testing. ">>}]}]}.
```

So here, using Strophe.js i send a custom IQ stanza with this function.

```
var iq = $iq( {type: 'get', id : 'id123', from : 'renato@localhost'}).c('query', {xmlns : 'jabber:iq:seen'});
connection.sendIQ(iq, onResult);
```

And it comes out with a Stanza like this.

```
<iq type="get" id="id123" from="renato@localhost" xmlns="jabber:client">
  <query xmlns="jabber:iq:seen" >
</iq>
```

Then i get disconnected and get no result from the server as expected. This is what i got in the log file.

```
2016-05-11 17:47:28.965 [info]<0.486.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:299      (#Port<0.3939>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:49120 -> 127.0.0.1:5280
2016-05-11 17:47:28.966 [info]<0.507.0>@ejabberd_http:init:157 started: {gen_tcp,#Port<0.3939>}
2016-05-11 17:47:29.511 [info]<0.509.0>@ejabberd_c2s:wait_for_sasl_response:932  ({socket_state,ejabberd_http_bind,{http_bind,<0.508.0>, {{127,0,0,1},49120}},ejabberd_http_bind}) Accepted authentication for renato  by undefined from 127.0.0.1
2016-05-11 17:47:30.150 [info]<0.509.0>@ejabberd_c2s:wait_for_session:1120  ({socket_state,ejabberd_http_bind,{http_bind,<0.508.0>, {{127,0,0,1},49120}},ejabberd_http_bind}) Opened session for  renato@localhost/32685205291462981649937971
2016-05-11 17:47:31.451 [info]<0.486.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:299 (#Port<0.3948>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:49122 -> 127.0.0.1:5280
2016-05-11 17:47:31.452 [info]<0.511.0>@ejabberd_http:init:157 started: {gen_tcp,#Port<0.3948>}
2016-05-11 17:47:31.453 [info]<0.390.0>@mod_test2:process_sm_iq:45   Processing IQ Get query:
{iq,<<"id123">>,get,<<"jabber:iq:seen">>,<<>>,{xmlel,<<"query">>, [{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:iq:seen">>},{<<"querytype">>,<<"seen">>}],[]}}    
2016-05-11 17:49:01.556 [info]<0.508.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_info:522 Session timeout. Closing the   HTTP bind session: <<"1199a026fb06de7e7c728425587b09a0b9c81433">>
2016-05-11 17:49:01.556 [info]<0.509.0>@ejabberd_c2s:terminate:1842  ({socket_state,ejabberd_http_bind,{http_bind,<0.508.0>,  {{127,0,0,1},49120}},ejabberd_http_bind}) Close session for   renato@localhost/32685205291462981649937971
```

I'm running ejabberd 15.07. I installed the run package and compiled the module using these commands.

```
erlc -DNO_EXT_LIB -I  lib/ejabberd-15.07/include -pz lib/ejabberd-15.07/lib  mod_test.erl
```

After that, i copied the file to ebin/ directory then i started the ejabberd server and everything else worked fine. Someone can help me out and explain me what i have to, and show me if i have to change the code, configuration file or maybe use a newer version. I'm using this version for months. Thanks...

Comment: Did you add `mod_test` to the list of modules in the configuration file?

Comment: yes i did and it loads fine. i get disconnected just when i send my custom stanza and the IQ handler is triggered!

Comment: there is problem in your Strophe.js code not in mod_test.

Comment: Which one? Strophe seems to send the stanza correctly. Can you explain me what problem could it be in strophe code?